# Failed to load nf_conntrack

Tags: centos, centos7

```
     [root@name ~]# systemctl status firewalld -l
        * firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon
           Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
           Active: inactive (dead)
             Docs: man:firewalld(1)

        Nov 17 18:47:24 strike325 systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
        Nov 17 18:47:25 strike325 systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
        Nov 17 18:47:25 strike325 firewalld[1176]: WARNING: ipset not usable, disabling ipset usage in firewall.
        Nov 17 18:47:26 strike325 firewalld[1176]: ERROR: Failed to load nf_conntrack module: modprobe: ERROR: could not find module by name='nf_conntrack'
                                                   modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nf_conntrack': Function not implemented
                                                   modprobe: ERROR: Error running install command for nf_conntrack
                                                   modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nf_conntrack': Operation not permitted
        Nov 17 18:47:26 strike325 firewalld[1176]: E

RROR: Raising SystemExit in run_server
    Nov 17 19:47:16 strike325 systemd[1]: Starting firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon...
    Nov 17 19:47:17 strike325 systemd[1]: Started firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon.
    Nov 17 19:47:17 strike325 firewalld[2689]: WARNING: ipset not usable, disabling ipset usage in firewall.
    Nov 17 19:47:18 strike325 firewalld[2689]: ERROR: Failed to load nf_conntrack module: modprobe: ERROR: could not find module by name='nf_conntrack'
                                               modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nf_conntrack': Function not implemented
                                               modprobe: ERROR: Error running install command for nf_conntrack
                                               modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nf_conntrack': Operation not permitted
    Nov 17 19:47:18 strike325 firewalld[2689]: ERROR: Raising SystemExit in run_server
```

I've recently purchased a VPS using Centos 7 (x64) and I'm having some trouble with my firewalld. I found the fix [here](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/519#issuecomment-546586485)  but unfortunately it's no longer working for me. Any help would be appreciated as I haven't been able to find any permanent fixes.

Other fix attempts so far:

1. restart dbus
2. restart firewalld
3. Reverting and locking the version of firewalld (temporary fix)

Answer (score 1):

I was going to post my fix in a while now (I'm supporting a number of servers, all affected with the same issue), but haven't had the time.

But your question made me motivated to finally [write it down](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/fix-firewalld-in-centos-7).

The solution from this post is:

- create a script which generates `modules.builtin` file specific to your current kernel
- create a SystemD unit which automatically recreates the same before FirewallD during startup (useful in case the kernel is upgraded).

In this way, you permanently solve the issue without hacking a bit of FirewallD code.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is to downgrade firewalld to 7.6:

```
wget http://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/os/x86_64/Packages/firewalld-0.5.3-5.el7.noarch.rpm http://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/os/x86_64/Packages/firewalld-filesystem-0.5.3-5.el7.noarch.rpm http://vault.centos.org/7.6.1810/os/x86_64/Packages/python-firewall-0.5.3-5.el7.noarch.rpm
yum downgrade firewalld-0.5.3-5.el7.noarch.rpm firewalld-filesystem-0.5.3-5.el7.noarch.rpm python-firewall-0.5.3-5.el7.noarch.rpm
```

and then lock firewalld from yum feature updates:

```
yum -y install yum-versionlock
yum versionlock firewalld firewalld-filesystem python-firewall
```

you can find more info in this [thread](https://github.com/firewalld/firewalld/issues/519).